# Find $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $\gamma$ is a path from $-i$ to $i$, whose image is contained in $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R^-$, find $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}z$

Does the integral converge ?, because the path $-i+2it, 0\le t\le1$ is also in $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R^-$ and for $t=1/2$ it is $0$

or can I use the fact that $f(z):=\frac1z$ is meromorphic with simple pole at $0$ and define

$\alpha_{\rho}(t):=0+\rho e^{it}, t\in[0,\pi]$  and then $\displaystyle\int_{\alpha_{\rho}}f(z)dz=\text{res}_0(f)\cdot \pi i$

with $\text{res}_0(f)=a_{-1}$ where $a_{-1}$ is the Laurent coefficient of $f$

Is the result $1$ ?

Comment: The author(s) probably denote $\mathbb{R}^- = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x \leqslant 0\}$. Otherwise, as you note, there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\gamma$ is *a* path from $i$ to $-i$, not necessarily a straight line which passes through $0$.

Since the image of $\gamma$ does not touch $\mathbb R^-$, it means that $\gamma$ cannot "turn around" $0$, so you can't really use the residue theorem because there are no residue in the inside of $\gamma$ (well $\gamma$ is not even a closed curve. But anyhow you can't close it such that $0$ is inside)

So any curve between those two points will result in the same integral.

How to do that? Well since we are on $\mathbb C - \mathbb R^-$, we have that $\log z$ is a holomorphic function (it's not multivalued anymore) and it's derivative is $\frac 1z$, we can use the usual formula;

The result depends only on the endpoints, and we get

$$\int_\gamma \frac 1z dz = \log(i) - \log(-i) =i \frac \pi2 - (-i\frac \pi2) = i\pi$$

Comment: You're assuming here, of course, the principal values of the corresponding arguments in $\;\log z\;$ .

Comment: @Ant I took the liberty of adding the missing "$i$'s" from the last expression.  I hope you don't mind my doing so.

Comment: @Dr.MV Of course! Thank you for the correction :-)

Comment: @Ant You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I cannot tell you how many typos I've made on this site.  And some users are fast to give a down vote rather than recognize sincere effort along with a typographical error.  Oh, well.  +1 for you!

Comment: @Ant, I am confused. Don't you think the integral is gonna pick a half residue on the way ?

Answer (score 2):

Inasmuch as @Ant has already provided an efficient approach, it might be instructive to see a more "brute force" approach.

To that end we parameterize $z$ on $\gamma$ and let $z=x(t)+iy(t)$, $0\le t\le 1$, with $x(0)=x(1)=0$, $y(0)=-1$, and $y(1)=1$.

Thus, $dz=x'(t)dt+iy'(t)dt$ and the integral of interest becomes

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z}&=\int_{0}^1\frac{x(t)x'(t)+y(t)y'(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}dt+i\int_{0}^1\frac{x(t)y'(t)-y(t)x'(t)}{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}dt\\\\
&=\left. \frac12 \log(x^2(t)+y^2(t))\right|_{t=0}^{t=1}+i\,\left.\arctan\left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}\right)\right|_{t=0}^{t=1}\\\\
&=(0-0)+i(\pi/2-(-\pi/2))\\\\
&=i\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

> **NOTE:  For a more general development, see [This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671).**

Comment: Thanks. but you assume $\frac10=\infty$ in the 3rd last line, actually clear but is it allowed ?

Comment: @inequal Technically, one ought to use a limit as $t \to 0$ and $t\to 1$.  But, the answer prevails. Another way is to redefine the anti-derivative to be $\arctan(y/x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $\pm \pi/2$ when $x=0$.  Thank you for your comment!