# How to integrate around a square

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to calculate the complex line integral of $f(z)=z^{-1}$ around the square of sides 2, centred at the origin counter clock wise. I know I cant use Cauchy theorem because of the singularity.

I thought maybe since f is holomorphic I could use the fundamental theorem, but then even nif my $F(z)=ln(z)$ I don't know what to use as my endpoints. I tried breaking it up into parts, ie end points at $1+i$ , $-1+i$, $-1-i$ and $1-i$, but when I compute using FTC that gives me 0. However, the correct answer I am told is $i2\pi$ ,

by the way , I also know that i2pi is the result of doing this integration but around a circle of radius irrelevant, maybe that could tie in somehow? I am looking for help. Thanks

Comment: $f$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: Is it holomorphic if we don't consider zero? Or since we are integrating around zero we cant do that?

Comment: You can't since the contour encloses a singularity.

Comment: Thanks more clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:**  Brute force valuation

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz&=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{t-i}\,dt+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{i}{it+1}\,dt-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{t+i}\,dt-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{i}{it-1}\,dt\\\\
&=4i\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt\\\\
&=4i \left.\left(\arctan(t)\right)\right|_{-1}^1\\\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:**  General Development

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671), I showed that for any rectifiable curve $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ from $1$ to $z$

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\,dz=\log(r)+i(\theta +2k\pi) \tag 1$$

where $r=|z|$, $\theta =\arg (z)\in [0,2\pi)$ and $k$ is equal to the **net** number of times that $\gamma$ crosses the positive real axis from the fourth quadrant to the first one.

Applying $(1)$ to the case for which $\gamma$ is the contour of interest, we see that $z=1$, $\theta =2\pi$, and $k=0$ so that

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}\,dz=2\pi i$$

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit new to integration especially complex etc so I am wondering if you can elaborate a bit more on method 1.  Why are you going from - 1 to 1? and where do you get the terms from?

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure. In Methodology $1$, the integration path is parameterized piecewise. For example, from $1−i$ to $1+i$, we can parameterize $z$ as $z=1+it$, where $dz=i\,dt$ and $t$ begins at $t=-1$ and ends at $t=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a good example of getting confused by parameterising curves, specifically the direction of your parameterisation. I tried to take shortcuts and got a result of zero as well, so I made the same mistake.

Let $C_{\pm}$ denote the vertical paths where $\mathfrak{R}(z) = \pm 1$. Then $z = \pm1 + t\mathrm{i}$, where $t \in [-1,1]$, then $\mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{i} \,\mathrm{d}t$ and
$$ f(z) = z^{-1} = \frac{1}{\pm1+t\mathrm{i}} = \frac{\pm1-t\mathrm{i}}{1+t^2}.$$
Integration gives
$$
\int_{C_{\pm}} f(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\pm \mathrm{i}}{1+t^2} + \frac{t} {1+t^2} \ \mathrm{d}t = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i} + 0.
$$

Let $\Gamma_{\pm}$ denote the horizontal paths where $\mathfrak{I}(z) = \pm 1$. Then $z = t \pm\mathrm{i}$, where $t \in [-1,1]$, then $\mathrm{d}z =  \mathrm{d}t$ and
$$ f(z) = z^{-1} = \frac{1}{t \pm\mathrm{i}} = \frac{t \mp \mathrm{i}}{t^2 + 1}.$$
Integration gives
$$
\int_{\Gamma_{\pm}} f(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{t}{1+t^2} \mp \frac{\mathrm{i}} {1+t^2} \ \mathrm{d}t = 0\mp\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i}.
$$

So far it does look like all these contributions cancel. However, note that going *counter clockwise* around the square, some of our parameterisations are around the wrong way.

Our integral is actually

$$
\int_{C_{+}} - \int_{\Gamma_{+}} - \int_{C_{-}} + \int_{\Gamma_{-}} = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i} - \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i} \right)- \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i} \right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{i} = 2\pi \mathrm{i}.
$$