# Log z derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If log z is not defined at the origin and negative axis then does it mean that 1/z  which is the the derivative of log z is not defined at negative axis and vice versa?

Comment: Yes.  If the logarithm function is defined on the sheet for which $-\pi+2k\pi <\theta\le \pi+2k\pi$, then $\frac{d \log(z)}{dz}=\frac1z$, for $-\pi+2k\pi <\theta\le \pi+2k\pi$.

Comment: What I mean is that logz is not continous at (-inf,0] but 1/z clearly is, why is that?

Comment: $1/z$ is holomorphic in the punctured plane.  And the integral $\int_1^z \frac{1}{w}\,dw=\log(z)$ when the path from $1$ to $z$ does not encircle the pole.  See [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) for details.

Comment: I know the that 1/z is holomorphic on punctured plane but for example in real plane, when a function is differentiable at a point, it's continuous at at that point, like wise, 1/z is a derivative of log(z) and it's continuous on negative axis except at origin, but the function log z is not continous at (-inf,0]. Why is that?

Comment: $1/z$ is NOT the derivative of $\log(z)$ along the branch cut.  
If a complex (or purely real function) is differentiable at a point, then it is continuous at that point.  What is the contrapositive of that statement?

Comment: A real-valued function that is not differentiable might still be continuous.  Take $f(x)=|x|$.  It is not differentiable at $x=0$, but is everywhere continuous.  Have you looked at the answer in the link I provided?

Answer (score 2):

> See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) for a detailed development of the evaluation of $\int_\gamma \frac1z'\,dz'$, where $\gamma$ is any rectifiable curve in $\mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$ from $1$ to $z$.

If the logarithm function is defined on the sheet for which $-\pi+2k\pi <\arg(z)\le \pi+2k\pi$, then

$$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i(\arg(z))$$

and

$$\frac{d \log(z)}{dz}=\frac1z$$

for $-\pi+2k\pi <\arg(z)\le \pi+2k\pi$.

Inasmuch as $\log(z)$ ***is*** defined, but discontinuous on the branch cut, it is clearly not differentiable there.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that $1/z$ isn't the derivative of $\log z$ on the nonpositive axis. The derivative of $\log z$ isn't defined when $\log z$ isn't differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually why we have

$$\int\frac1xdx=\ln|x|+c$$

And by practical means, since it is impossible to integrate over $x=0$, this definition works fine.