# Logarithm over complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

The logarithm function is not certainly defined for every $\text{Re}(z)\leq0$, but the question is where is it defined?

I also know $\displaystyle \int_{C} \frac{1}{z} dz\neq0$ where $C$ is the unit circle defined by $ \gamma(t)=e^{it} $ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, which implies that $\frac{1}{z}$ has no antiderivative.

Is this true because any set $U\supset C$ contains $z\in \mathbb{C}:Re(z)\leq0$ ?

If $U$ does not contain $z\in \mathbb{C}:Re(z)\leq0$ , is $\log(z)$ "well behaved" in $U$?

Comment: As you have very well seen: it is problematic as soon as you "go around zero". Indeed, you can show that whenever you look at a set $U$ which does "not go around zero", then you can define a complex logarithm.

Comment: [See This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) for details on integration  $\int_C \frac1z\,dz$ where $C$ is a rectifiable path..

Comment: $f(z)=\int_1^z \frac1u du$ is said locally analytic (away from $0$), its value depends on the chosen path, and $z = \exp(f(z))$ whatever the one you choose.

Comment: Though you can proceed even more generally, you can make sense of the logarithm on any set with $\{ c e^{i\theta} : c \geq 0 \}$ excluded, for any fixed $\theta$. These logarithms are different for different $\theta$, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you should do is to remove from your mind the concept of THE logarithm function, and replace it with A logarithm function. Once you've done that, then you can formulate a sensible question:

> On what (open) subsets $U \subset \mathbb C - \{0\}$ does there exist a logarithm function $l : U \to \mathbb C$?

And you can even say precisely what you mean by this, namely that $l$ is holomorphic on $U$ and the composition $z \mapsto \exp(l(z))$, when restricted to $U$, is the identify function on $U$.

To start, here's some examples: for each angle $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ a logarithm is defined on the domain $U_\theta$ obtained by removing the ray of angle $\theta$ from $\mathbb C$, which is given by the formula
$$U_\theta = \{r e^{2 \pi i \phi} \mid r > 0, \,\, \theta - 2\pi < \phi < \theta\}
$$
For more examples, every [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) open subset $U \subset \mathbb C - \{0\}$ has a logarithm.

And here is a reasonably simple general answer to this question: a logarithm is defined on $U$ if and only if for every smooth Jordan curve $C$ in $U$, the curve $C$ does not wind around the origin, equivalently $\int_C \frac{dz}{z}=0$.

Comment: I think this is not stated *quite* correctly. Consider $l(z)$ given by $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ off the negative real axis and given by $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Log}(z+i\epsilon)$ on the negative real axis. I'm pretty sure that $\exp(l(z))=z$ for all $z \neq 0$. The issue is that my $l$ is not continuous on the negative real axis.

Comment: You are right, it was only implicit, but I made it explicit, that $l(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, +1.