# What is the integral of $1/x$ on the entire complex plane?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals, inverse

Usually, when one asks for the integral of $1/x$, they’ll be answered with “$ln(x)$”, but it’s “undefined” for negative values.

Sometimes, they’ll be answered with “$ln(|x|)$”, which *is* defined in the entire real numbers line (except $0$, but that doesn’t matter).

However, this only works for real values and I’ve never heard of complex values being discussed.

So that leaves me with the question of what that ever elusive integral is.

My first idea was that, on the unit circle, $1/x=x^*$, and that $x^*= e^{-i\theta}$. Integrating that gives $e^{i\theta}/-i\theta=ie^{-i\theta}/\theta$

I was going to check it on $1$, but I realized that division by $\theta$ doesn’t lend itself well to real values.

Other than that, I don’t really know what to do.

Comment: $\mathrm{Ln}(x)$ is not a single valued function on the complex numbers.

Comment: I never said anything about $ln$ on the entire complex plane

Comment: To elaborate further on the comment by @Trebor: The antiderivative of $1/x$ would have to agree with $\ln x$ for $x > 0$, up to a constant. And that function can indeed be continued for complex values. But you don't get a single valued function when you do that. And you can never get a meaningful definition for this antiderivative at $x = 0$, because this already fails when you just look at positive real $x$.

Comment: [See THIS](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) detailed development of the integral of $\displaystyle \frac1z$ over arbitrary rectifiable curves in the complex plane.

Comment: @Mark Viola this was meant to be the indefinite integral of $1/z$, not the integral over a curve

Comment: @LaveCave That is the point.  The indefinite integral is the complex logarithm, a multi-valued function and undefined along a chosen branch cut from $0$ to the point at infinity.

Comment: @Mark Viola would that mean that the absolute value is unnecessary for the antiderivative for real values of x? Also, if you chose a branch cut, then the other branches are just $ln(x)+C$, so the constant deals with the multi valuedness

Comment: The absolute value on $\log(|x|)$ is used when integrating $\frac1x$ over the negative real axis.  For example, $\int_{-|b|}^{-|a|}\frac1x\,dx=\log(|a/b|)$.  If we cut the plane along the negative real axis and choose the branch for which $\log(1)=0$, then we have $\int_{-|b|}^{-|a|}\frac1x\,dx=(\log(|a|)+i\pi) -(\log(|b|)+i\pi)=\log(|a/b|)$ as expected.