# Logarithm of a holomorphic complex function on a simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if $f$ is a nonvanishing holomorphic function on a simply connected region $\Omega$, then we can define $\log(f)(z)$ to be
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{f'(\omega)}{f(\omega)}\ d\omega + c_0$$
where $\gamma$ is a path from a fixed point $z_0 \in \Omega$ to $z$ and $c_0$ is just a choice of branch such that $e^{c_0} = f(z_0)$.

I understand the proof and I am confused when I see it from the definition of complex logarithm of complex numbers. To define complex logarithm holomorphically, we need to take a branch cut. The condition of defining $\log(f)$ only requires $f$ to be nonzero. It does not guarantee that the image of $f$ will not circle around.

Just like in the complex plane when I traverse the unit circle from 1 to 1 counterclockwise, the argument changes from $0$ to $2\pi$ so that I have some nontrivial monodromy here.

How to guarantee that the argument of $f(z)$ will not change when I travel from $z_0$ to $z_0$? This question sounds dumb but I just want to have some better understanding.

Comment: [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is topological: If $\gamma$ is a closed path in the simply-connected region $\Omega$, then $\gamma$ is homotopic in $\Omega$ to a constant path, so the image path $f \circ \gamma$ in $f(\Omega)$ is homotopic in $f(\Omega)$ to a constant path *whether or not* $f(\Omega)$ is simply-connected. (Proof: Compose $f$ with a trivializing homotopy for $\gamma$.)

In other words, $f(\Omega)$ may admit closed loops not homotopic to a constant, but no such loop is the image under $f$ of a loop in $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand it better now. It somehow connects what I learnt in algebraic topology to what I learnt in complex analysis. Now everything makes sense.

Comment: I recall being puzzled as a student by this point as well! It was pleasant to realize integrating $f'/f$ can be viewed as lifting the path $f \circ \gamma$ to the Riemann surface of $\log$, which can be viewed as the universal cover of the punctured plane with $\exp$ as covering map. This path can wind around the origin, but only if the lift moves to another sheet.

Comment: Apropos of nothing, the other Big Revelation (for me) between complex analysis and topology is the proof of Big Picard: The unit disk is the holomorphic universal cover of the twice-punctured plane. (Showing this is most of the work of the proof. If memory serves, Ahlfors has a good explanation.) Consequently, an entire function that misses two values lifts to an entire function to the disk, which is constant by Liouville.