# Prove that $ \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $\displaystyle\gamma$ be a closed curve exactly located in $A =\mathbb C \setminus\{z\in\mathbb C: Re(z)\leq 0\}$.

I found a similar problem here :
[Find $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289651/find-int-gamma-fracdzz), but they concluded that the value of the contour integral is $\displaystyle i\pi$.

How does the result changes for this problem?

Comment: The result is not necessarily true, you don't have the condition that $\gamma$ must be closed.

Comment: Your question is not specified enough, since we know nothing about the start and end of the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: I edited the question, $\gamma$ is a closed curve over $A=\mathbb C \setminus \{z\in\mathbb C : Re(z) \leq 0\}$

Comment: $1/z$ is holomorphic in $A$ and $\gamma$ is closed, so the integral is $0$.

Comment: The previous remarks implicitly give you the answer.

Comment: [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513008/the-line-integral-int-gamma-frac-1z-and-branchs-of-logarithm/1513671#1513671) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite topological. If you are familiar with differential forms, you’d notice $\frac {1}{z}$ is holomorphic in $A$. Hence $\frac {\mathrm{d}z}{z}$ is a closed form. Further notice, $A$ is simply connected, hence the the closed form $\frac {\mathrm{d}z}{z}$ is actually an exact form. So it must have $0$ integral on any closed path.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Cauchy's integral theorem you can use that $\gamma$ is closed and $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic in $A$, so the theorem say that the integral is zero.

However I think the easy way is notice that in $A$ the principal branch of the complex logarithm is well defined, so you can use that $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \log(z)$, so the integral is

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} \,\mathrm{d}z = \log(\gamma(0)) - \log (\gamma(1)) = 0$$ because the curve is closed, so $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$.

Edit: Here I'm thinking in $\gamma$ parameterized in the unit interval, i.e. $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow A$.

Comment: That’s exactly what my point was. Branch of logarithm exists because the geometry of  $A$ is nice (ie. simply connected, that’s the key point here). Anyway i think this answer is more accessible to someone who’s not yet exposed to some differential form or algebraic topology.

Comment: Yes, using algebraic topology you have a more directly argument. $\pi_1(A,0)=\{e\}$ because $A$ in simply connected as you say, so every loop (in this case $\gamma$) is equivalently homotopic to a point, so the integral has to be zero.